# ReferenceError: $get is not defined using jquery in asp.net vs 2010

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

Struggling to wire up jquery in a new VS 2010 asp.net project.

Created a new Web App Project (with master page & other defaults)
Drug jquery from the Scripts folder into Site.Master file and got:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(between  and )
Added a textbox and this button to Default.aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="debugger; $get('TextBox1').value = 'hello';" />
```

Hit F5, which launched the app and opened the page in firefox
Enabled firebug.  On the script tab it lists jquery-1.4.1.min and shows it's contents.
Hit the button, which opens the debugger paused on the 'debugger;' statement
Clicked to step $get() and got the message: ReferenceError $get is not defined.

Any help greatly appreciated.  Everything looking right until the last click.

Comment: I'm not VS guru but can you inspect your page and verify if the line `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` exists?

Comment: Can you please post the html for your text box?

Comment: So where did you come up with `$get()` in your `OnClientClick`? The error is pretty clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the jQuery documentation.[$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is used to perform an HTTP GET request from the server.If you need to set a value of `TextBox` on button click you should do something like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setValue() {
            $("#" + "<%: TextBox1.ClientID %>").val("Hello");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return setValue()" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: It's possible that your code will work incorrect. `$('#TextBox1')` possible return nothing becouse server-side controls may change their ID's. ASP.NET can add some additional info to the IDs.

Comment: You're right, that is possible.I've updated my answer.Thank you!

Comment: My mistake, followed an example that uses $get() from MicrosoftAjax.debug.js, thought it was jquery. ;(

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is something like:

```
$("input[name='TextBox1']").val("hello")
```

I am assuming your text box field has a name `TextBox1` but you could just replace `name` with whatever attribute you have set to `TextBox1`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all jQuery don't have any `$get` function.

If I'm right you want to get the some textbox with `ID` that equals `TextBox1` and update its value. So if you use server-side `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"/>` I think you have two possible solutions:

1.Save `TextBox1`'s `ClientID` into JavaScript variable and than use it:

```
<script>
    var id = "<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>";
    function onClick() { 
        debugger; 
        $('#' + id).val('hello'); 
        return false;
    };
</script>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return onClick()" />
```

2.Change your server-side control `<asp:TextBox .../>` to client-side control `<input id="TextBox1" >`:

```
<script>
    function onClick() {
        debugger; 
        $('#TextBox1').val('hello'); 
        return false;
    }
</script>
<input id="TextBox1"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onClientClick="return onClick()" />
```

Comment: So sorry for the spin!  Haven't been in html/js for years and following a working example in another project where jquery is the only .js file in the folder.  But stepped into $get() in that project and landed in MicrosoftAjax.debug.js.  No $get() in jquery!  Again, so sorry for the spin.